# Android volley stop or limit response.length() loop

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have an android program use Volley StringRequest with dynamic ListView, but
i have a case that in android monitor after i got all my data it's still loop to next index. I just want to stop the loop when i already get all of my data.

MyActivity.java

```
...@Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.d("RES-GET:", response);

                    for(int i = 0; i<response.length();i++){
                    try { //mengubah response dari String -> JsonObject & diparsing

                        //Parse String to JSONObject
                        JSONObject objUser = new JSONObject(response);

                        Log.d("Dep-JSONObj", objUser.toString());

                        ...

                        //view departement
                        Departement dept = new Departement(dep.getNamadept(), dep.getSubtitle(), dep.getDetail());

                        deptList.add(dept); //method from other activity to set view departement

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        //Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + response + "\"");
                    }
                    }mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(DeptActivity.this, "Service getdepartment() : GAGAL !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }); ...
```

[ImageOne.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhLcJ.jpg)

[ImageTwo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXfGg.jpg)

In this pictures, i had 2 index (index 0 and index 1) but it still loop until 458 loops. How to stop the loop when index 1 has executed ?

Comment: what do you think `for(int i = 0; i<response.length();i++){` does?

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the loop `for(int i = 0; i<response.length();i++){`

this actually loops trough every character in the response and in every iteration you call `JSONObject objUser = new JSONObject(response);` which parses the same JSON over and over again